# Struct string array print last entered element

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to print all entered elements.  Instead, my code prints the most recently entered element twice.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(struct ar *a);
void d(struct ar *a);
struct ar
{
    char name[50];
};
int main()
{
    struct ar a;
    f(&a);
    d(&a);
}
void f(struct ar *a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("enter name:");
        gets(a->name);
    }
}
void d(struct ar *a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        puts(a->name);
    }
}
```

For example:

Input

```
name:john

name:kendall
```

Output

```
kendall

kendall
```

Comment: You shall never use `gets()` use `fgets()` instead. This is what *gcc* says about it **warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.**

Comment: You need create a linked list. [Linked data Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data_structure)

Comment: So in your loops you are getting/printing `a->name` twice without moving it anywhere. So what are you expecting to get?

Comment: @chengpohi I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are overwriting the value in each iteration.

You can create an array in `main()` and pass the array to the functions so the values are stored in different places, instead you always pass the same structure instance to `gets()` and hence overwrite the previous value, so the printing loop prints the **same data** twice.

The following demonstrate how to pass an array

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Data
 {
    char name[50];
 };

void readData(struct Data *array);
void showData(struct Data *array);

int main()
 {
    struct Data array[2];

    readData(array);
    showData(array);
 }

void readData(struct Data *array)
 {
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
     {
        printf("enter name: ");
        fgets(array[i].name, sizeof(array[i].name), stdin);
     }
 }

void showData(struct Data *array)
 {
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
     {
        printf("%s", array[i].name);
     }
 }
```

Also, don't be lazy when it comes to naming identifiers, even for a simple demonstration they help make the program intent clear and they help you maintain it forever, if you think that doesn't matter, then I am afraid you will have a lot of problems when you work on a real life project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will consider your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here you are taking the inputs twice in same variable. So what the happening is:

- In the first iteration the input is getting stored in `ar->name`. The first input is `john`, so `ar->name="john"`
- In the next iteration the input is also getting stored in `ar->name`. So if your input is `kendall` then `ar->name="kenadall"`.

For this reason the `john` value is getting overwritten by `kendall` and when you are printing you are getting the `kendall` value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Linked List` to do the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Data
{
    char name[50];
    struct Data *next;
};

struct Data *readData();
void showData(struct Data *array);

int main()
{
    struct Data *array;

    array = readData();
    showData(array);
}

struct Data *readData()
{
    int i;
    struct Data *tmp = NULL;
    struct Data *head = NULL;
    struct Data *end = head;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        tmp = (struct Data *)malloc(sizeof(struct Data));
        printf("enter name: ");
        fgets(tmp->name, sizeof(tmp->name), stdin);
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = tmp;
        } else {
            end->next = tmp;
        }
        end = tmp;
    }
    return head;
}

void showData(struct Data *array)
{
    int i;
    struct Data *a = array;
    while(a != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", a->name);
        a = a->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
gets(a->name);
```

you are recording the user input to same place each time the for loop runs.  Instead, try something like

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Name
{
  char first[50];
  char last[50];
};

void recordName(struct Name *name); //writes Name structs
void reportName(struct Name *name); //prints contents of Name structs


int main()
{
  struct Name test_Name;

  recordName(&test_Name);
  reportName(&test_Name);

  return 0;
}

void recordName(struct Name *name)
{
  printf("enter first Name: ");
  fgets(name->first,sizeof(name->first),stdin);

  printf("enter last Name: ");
  fgets(name->last,sizeof(name->last),stdin);
}


void reportName(struct Name *name)
{
  printf("%s%s",name->first, name->last);
}
```